# :not(.active) selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a simple CSS :not selector:

```
$('.UISelect.popover:not(.active)').click(function () {

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

});
```

A click adds the class .active to the .UISelect.popover:

```
<a class="UISelect popover active">jow</a>
```

The :not(.active) selector should prevent removing the .active on the second click.

---

However, the problem is that it toggles the .active class on every click. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: "The :not(.active) selector should prevent removing the .active on the second click."
But why you use then toggleClass and Not addClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to just add the class, no matter whether or not it already has it. You don't need to check whether it already has the class before adding it, jQuery checks for uniqueness for you.

```
$('.UISelect.popover').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That happens because the click event is set forever in the dom element.

This should fix it:

```
$('.UISelect.popover').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', !$(this).is('.active'));
});
```

When you declare events they are bound to the node. Independently of whatever classes you have on them when the click actually triggers. Your only solution is to verify it when the click triggers.

Luckily the `toggleClass` accepts a second argument (true/false), so you don't need to actually put an `if` around it. With `true` it will add the class, `false` it will remove it.

Comment: Right the event handlers are assigned on page load

Comment: @PatBurke not necessarily on page load. You can register events to DOM nodes whenever you want. But yes normally ppl set them after the DOM finished loading.

Comment: True, I was speaking generally about the common case. Should have been more clear.

Comment: Damn i'm a newbie... i don't get it... i used your exact code instead of my code and it doesn't work. It still removes the .active class on the second click